# how do i get a value picked from another screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

im using navigation to pass between screens.
now,im trying to figure out how can i get a value from second screen to the first screen ?
the user needs to pick a color value from the second screen and return selcted color to the first screen.
this is the code im using .

```
enter code here
      <CustomButton
        style={styles.buttonPicker}
        darkMode={this.props.darkMode}
        title={'pick a color'}
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('ColorPickerScreen', {
            onSubmit: (namecolor) => {
              console.log('55555555555555', { getNameColor })
            },
          })
        }}
      ></CustomButton>

enter code here
```

onSelect = (color) => this.props.navigation.navigate('CreatenewtTipul')
render() {
return (

<Image
style={styles.img}
source={require('../components/icons/color-wheel.png')}
/>

```
    <ColorPicker
      colors={this.state.colors}
      selectedColor={this.state.selectedColor}
      onSelect={this.onSelect}
    />

    <Text>Selected Color = {this.state.selectedColor}</Text>
  </View>
)
```

}
}

tnx for any help
arik :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as a callback from the first screen to the second screen in params on call that on your second screen.

```
function Screen1(props) {
   const onSelect = (selectedColor) => {
     console.log('selectedColor', selectedColor)
   }
   const navigateToSecondScreen = () => {
     props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
       onColorSelect: onSelect
    })
   }
   return(
     <View>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigateToSecondScreen}>
         <Text>Go to second screen</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   )
}

//Second Screen

function Screen2(props) {
  const {onColorSelect} = props.route.params;
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {onColorSelect('color value')}}>
        <Text>your other code here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The idea is just to call the function which you have passed as a param from Screen1

Answer (score 0):

To pass value from screen A to screen B:

```
navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
```

To access that value in Screen A:

```
const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params;
```

Where were route here is part of the screen's props, check the guide [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

im not trying to pass a value to the second screen.
im trying to get a value from the second screen to the first screen.